# Summing the values in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary

How would you add together all the values in a given map?

```
private final Map<String, Double> deviceVoltageMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();

synchronized public double getVoltage(String device) {
    double totalVolts = 0.0;
    for (String key : deviceVoltageMap.keySet()) {
         //?
        }
    return totalVolts;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the values using `Map#values()`!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (String key : deviceVoltageMap.keySet()) {
        totalVolts += deviceVoltageMap.get(key);
}
```

[Map.get(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

Alternatively:

```
for(Double value : deviceVoltageMap.values()){
  totalVolts += value;
}
```

[Map.values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29)

Alternatively alternatively:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : deviceVoltageMap.entrySet()){
   totalVolts += entry.getValue();
}
```

[Map.entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you don't need the key for anything, so it's possible to simply iterate over the values in the `Map`. Try this:

```
double totalVolts = 0.0;
for (Double val : deviceVoltageMap.values()) {
     totalVolts += val;
}
```